# Get event click link in a webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview and have some links in that webview.Now,I need that when i click a link in webview,a dialog is show...How must I do?

Comment: Use `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`

Comment: You should check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973767/progress-bar-only-work-on-loading-page

Answer (score 9):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                                                 ^^^
          // HERE YOU GET url
          return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create interfaces between your JavaScript code and client-side Android code.
With that your JavaScript code can call a method in your Android code to display a Dialog.

There is a good example over here:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript