# Fetch URL of current page from WebView

Tags: android, url, download, android-webview

I have a link which contains collection of books (for eg. *www.bookstore.com*), from which I select one book (with URL *www.bookstore.com/book1.epub*) which should be downloaded to my library when user clicks on Download button of that book.

I'm done with download part but what is bothering to me is How will I get the URL of specific book which has been selected by user to download i.e. *www.bookstore.com/book1.epub* ?

I tried with `webView.getUrl()`, but it doesn't get fired at all except for first load when it's null.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11528149/1289716

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to implement `WebViewClient`.

Where inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, you will be having current URL:

```
@Override  
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

       // Log.d("URL => ", url);    // current URL
       view.loadUrl(url);  
       return true;  
 }
```

Read more about WebView and WebViewClient => [WebView | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Thnx a ton... It's working... But I have a query. If I navigate from collection of books to specific book from pc browser and from webview. Both navigates correctly, but **both URL's are not same**.

Comment: If I navigate using pc browser, I get (http://www.flipkart.com/think-grow-rich-0091900212/p/itmczyztt3y3fyps?pid=9780091900212&ref=93b53224-1bc1-4176-ad61-801df65702cd)  but in webview.loadUrl, I get (http://www.flipkart.com/think-grow-rich-0091900212/p/itmczyztt3y3fyps?pid=9780091900212&ref=28d0b6bf-8963-4653-9705-d4af46a207b9
). Both URL's are slightly different but actually both re-directs to same page.

Comment: It will return you the current URL which is loaded in Webview.