# How to show loading bar as page loads in android webview?

Tags: android, webview, loading

I want that a loading bar must be shown as page loads and when we click any link on that loaded page then also a loading bar must be shown as next clicked page loads....i am using webview.

Answer (score 1):

Loading bar can be displayed by overriding onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() of webviewclient.
Start displaying loading bar in onPageStarted and and make it invisible in onPageFinished.

Comment: i did that but when another link is clicked on the page background image becomes black rather showing last page that we've opened...

Comment: can refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973767/progress-bar-only-work-on-loading-page)