# Detect if CheckBox is checked and call Visibility - Android

Tags: android, checkbox, visibility

How to make the visibility method used in onpagestarted and onpagefinished detect whether a checkbox is checked ? in other words, i want to modify and use this method for checkBoxes .for example if R.id.checkBox1 is checked, make R.id.progressbar1 visible And if R.id.checkBox1 and R.id.checkBox2 BOTH are checked, make R.id.progressbar2 visible and R.id.progressbar1 Invisible

```
  here is my updated main activity


package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends Activity {

CheckBox checkBox_one  = null;
CheckBox checkBox_two = null;
CheckBox checkBox_three = null;
CheckBox checkBox_four = null;
CheckBox checkBox_five = null;
ProgressBar progressBar1;
ProgressBar progressBar2;
CheckBox checkBox1;
CheckBox checkBox2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);




    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });
    }

    public void updateProgressBars() {

      progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }






      //SAVE CHECKBOX STATE//

      checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

      boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
      Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
      checkBox_one.setChecked(isChecked);
      checkBox_one.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
      checkBox_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
        }
      });

      checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

      boolean isCheckedTwo = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedTwo");
      checkBox_two.setChecked(isCheckedTwo );
      checkBox_two.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
      checkBox_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedTwo");
        }
      });

      checkBox_three = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

      boolean isCheckedThree = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedThree");
      checkBox_three.setChecked(isCheckedThree );
      checkBox_three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedThree");
        }
      });

      checkBox_four = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

      boolean isCheckedFour = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFour");
      checkBox_four.setChecked(isCheckedFour );
      //checkBox_four.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
      checkBox_four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFour");
        }
      });

      checkBox_five = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

      boolean isCheckedFive = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFive");
      checkBox_five.setChecked(isCheckedFive );
      checkBox_five.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFive");
        }
      });

    }

    public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();        
    }
    public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return isChecked;       

    }
    //-------------------------//


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // Stop back button Functioning
    }

    public void openrate1(View view) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Rate.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void gotohome(View view) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void savesettings(View view) { 
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Settings successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
        toast.show();   
        }                       

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to a Settings activity i suggest you to you Default preferenceActivity. And why do you want to show progress bar. Is it for saving settings. If It is, you don't need to use it. Because saving settings is a very fast.

You already write some thing for saving and reading Settings. You can use it in your listener like you used before.

You can use simple if checks for that

```
   package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends Activity {

CheckBox checkBox_one  = null;
CheckBox checkBox_two = null;
CheckBox checkBox_three = null;
CheckBox checkBox_four = null;
CheckBox checkBox_five = null;
ProgressBar progressBar1;
ProgressBar progressBar2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);  

    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

      checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
      checkBox_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
      });

      checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
      checkBox_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
      });   
}

public void updateProgressBars() {

   progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   progressBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

   if (checkBox_one.isChecked() && checkBox_two.isChecked()) {
      progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else if (checkBox_one.isChecked()) {
      progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you Please try to explain what do you want to achieve? Or just post your code at your questions. I think there is a simple thing you missed in your code? And did you try my answer?

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve? This code work like this; If you checked checkBox_one it will show progressBar1. If checkBox_one and checkBox_two checked both, progressBar1 will be invisible, progressBar2 will be visible.

Comment: I just remove unnecessary part of code. It is simple now. Can you try it?

Comment: i tried but i am confused , please help me with the code for saving checkBox state

Comment: hello there, please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844438/call-visibility-onpagefinished-android

Comment: here is an answer but it also didnt help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331506/how-to-show-loading-bar-as-page-loads-in-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

To query checkbox state, use it's isChecked() method:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```